# ActiveXObject works in IE, but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, activexobject

`new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")` this activex works in ie but not in firefox anybodies know the equivalents to firefox, chrome, safari, opera, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. ActiveX is an IE-only thing. If you need cross-browser support, you're gonna have to re-think what you're trying to do...

Answer (score 0):

ActiveXObject only works in IE, maybe you should try and explain what you want to achieve?

I'm guessing it has something to do with file handling, more specifically I'm guessing it has something to do with uploading, in that case [you probably want to do it in flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152677/flash-file-upload-vs-php-file-upload-which-one-to-choose).

Comment: well i just want to do file handling (reading and writing)....problem i m facing is this that i m using ActiveX..which is only supportable by IE nt other browsers...!

Answer (score 0):

I have a newer implementation of an ActiveX host for Firefox & Chrome. The project is hosted on Google Code - http://code.google.com/p/ff-activex-host/.

It provides some security measures such as site and CLSID/PROGID locking, so that you can make sure no one can exploit it for running any ActiveX out there.

It's directed at web developers, not end users, as the plugin needs to be compiled with the correct security settings before distribution.

EDIT: You still won't be able to use IE-compatible JS/HTML code to create ActiveX objects, you'll need to use a slightly different notation. Just a bit more secure.

Answer (score 0):

I think this site will help you better to understand the ActiveX because this is Microsoft Technology.

Even now they say goodbye to ActiveX object in new Windows 10.
Edge don't support the ActiveX object. Only Internet Explorer supports an ActiveX object.

Please check out this link for more information.

[ActiveX Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751968(v=vs.85).aspx)