# upload large files 100MB+ progress

Tags: php, file-upload, large-files, swfupload

I am having a lot of trouble handling large file uploading on the client side. I am looking for a way to show the progress of an upload while that person uploads. Then when it is finished, I need to have the file handled by a php script.

I am currently using http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/ SWFUPLOAD, but it is giving me trouble. It works 100% of the time for small files that are 5MB and so on, but for larger files that are over 100MB I am getting weird behavior. For example, when finished, the upload script does not receive some of the posted variables sometimes and so on. It seems to be breaking for reasons I cannot diagnose and I am quite frankly completely sick of it. (PS all my php settings are fine).

I am just looking for a simple solution for upload progress that does not have too many bells and whistles. I just want the ability to upload large files 100MB-500MB and then have the form posted to an upload script without the client side solution hanging or causing problems.

- Has anyone worked on a project that required uploading large files and displaying progress? If so, what was your solution?

  - Did it involve flash?
  - Does anyone have any recommendations or a reliable solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you on a hosted site or a dedicated server that you control?

Comment: Dedicated. Are you thinking of jquery and the uploadprogress module?

Comment: @Scarface, uploadprogress and jQuery are what I used to handle 1 MB - 1 GB file uploads on a intranet application I worked on.  If you are a good coder, that is the way to go, very straight forward and efficient.

Comment: Probably related: [Upload 1GB files using chunking in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447837/upload-1gb-files-using-chunking-in-php), [Flash file upload vs php file upload - which one to choose?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152677/flash-file-upload-vs-php-file-upload-which-one-to-choose)

Comment: Alright thanks guys, I will give uploadprogress a go and let you know. I am so sick of flash and complex handlers right now.

Answer (score 1):

PHP have a restriction for upload files, you can modify this argument in PHP.ini, but if you can't have access to PHP.ini (some webhosting don't give access to PHP.ini) you can try upload file via FTP.

Can try with [this](http://www.cristalab.com/tutoriales/subir-archivos-con-php-por-ftp-c112l/) (is in spanish) or with [another good](http://blog.unijimpe.net/ftp-upload-con-php/).